# XSLT copy all XML nodes except one node, modify it conditionally

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML (simplified):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <person>
        <details>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>Peter</name>
            <salary>100</salary>
            <age>29</age>
        </details>
    </person>
    <person>
        <details>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>Oliver</name>
            <salary>500</salary>
            <age>13</age>
        </details>
    </person>
</root>
```

I need to transform this xml to the following format:

```
<another-root>
    <insert>
        <info>
            <name>Peter</name>
            <salary>0</salary>
            <age>29</age>
        </info>
    </insert>
    <insert>
        <info>
            <name>Oliver</name>
            <salary>500</salary>
            <age>13</age>
        </info>
    </insert>
</another-root>
```

Note the following:

1- I have many other nodes (children of person),

2- so I need to copy all the children of person,

3- except one child which is the id,

4- and if the id = 1 I need to set the salary to 0

I have tried the following xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <another-root>  
      <xsl:for-each select="root/person">
          <Insert>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </Insert>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </another-root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="details">
    <info>
        <xsl:copy-of select="./node()[not(self::id)]" />
    </info>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="details[id=1]/salary">
    <salary>0</salary>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It does the job correctly except one thing, that is: if the id = 1 I need to set the salary to 0.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach is to start with the identity transformation and then to write a template for each element you want to transform, the one you want to remove gets an empty template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <another-root>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </another-root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="person">
      <insert>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </insert>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="details">
      <info>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </info>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="details/id"/>

  <xsl:template match="details[id = 1]/salary">
      <xsl:copy>0</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncntCS4